# Rspec: "array.should == another_array" but without concern for order

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I often want to compare arrays and make sure that they contain the same elements, in any order. Is there a concise way to do this in RSpec?

Here are methods that aren't acceptable:

### `#to_set`

For example:

```
expect(array.to_set).to eq another_array.to_set
```

or

```
array.to_set.should == another_array.to_set
```

This fails when the arrays contain duplicate items.

### `#sort`

For example:

```
expect(array.sort).to eq another_array.sort
```

or

```
array.sort.should == another_array.sort
```

This fails when the arrays elements don't implement `#<=>`

Comment: Not to smartass, but comparing `to_set` and `size` actually doesn't do what you want.  E.g. [a, b, b] would match [a, a, b].  Cheers!

Comment: For those who stumbled here wondering the opposite: **order should be the same**. Use the `eq` matcher, e.g. `expect([1, 2]).to_not eq([2, 1])`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`match_array`](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:match_array), which takes another array as an argument, or [`contain_exactly`](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:contain_exactly), which takes each element as a separate argument, and is sometimes useful for readability.

Examples:

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array [3, 2, 1]
```

or

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to contain_exactly 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 274):

Try `array.should =~ another_array`

The best documentation on this I can find is the code itself, which is [here](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/match_array.rb).

Comment: This doesn't take the order in account, so this is not an acceptable answer, is it? Quote from the [docs](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/match_array.rb#L56): `Passes if actual contains all of the expected regardless of order.`.

Comment: Title of this post: "Rspec: “array.should == another_array” but without concern for order"

Comment: This is now officially documented under [operator matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers/operator-matchers)

Comment: If you're using the new "expect" syntax found in rspec 3.0, see the answer from @JoshKovach.

Comment: **Rspec 3.0** syntax is `expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array([2, 1, 3])` see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19436763/33226

Comment: how do you access the error message in the case of a mismatch ? I am trying to use this to describe the mismatch between two arrays within two higher level objects

Comment: Adding to what @GavinMiller mentioned (and as pointed out in the references SO link), `match_array` is an alias for `contain_exactly`, as seen in the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher)

Answer (score 273):

Since RSpec 2.11 you can also use `match_array`.

```
array.should match_array(another_array)
```

Which could be more readable in some cases.

```
[1, 2, 3].should =~ [2, 3, 1]
# vs
[1, 2, 3].should match_array([2, 3, 1])
```

Comment: yup, just upgraded to rails 4 and =~ stopped working where match_array works fine, thanks!

Comment: I dunno if that is more readable. Now it reads like it should be an exact match, but it isn't. The previous squiggle was vague enough to mean nothing for an array, so I didn't have the preconception. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: For "exact", you always have `eq()`, so I guess `match_array()` is vague enough for me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on ordered lists.  It thinks lists, which have the same items in a different order, are the same. :-(

Comment: FWIW `match_array` is an alias for `contain_exactly` ([documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher))

Answer (score 147):

I've found `=~` to be unpredictable and it has failed for no apparent reason. Past 2.14, you should probably use

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array([2, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Also valid past 3.0: `expect([1, 2, 3]).to contain_exactly(2, 3, 1)`. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher

Answer (score 17):

For RSpec 3 use [`contain_exactly`](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:contain_exactly):

> The contain_exactly matcher provides a way to test arrays against each other in a way that disregards differences in the ordering between the actual and expected array.

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to    contain_exactly(2, 3, 1) # pass
expect([:a, :c, :b]).to contain_exactly(:a, :c) # fail
```

As others have pointed out, if you want to assert the opposite, that the arrays should match both contents and order, then use `eq`, ie.:

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).to     eq([1, 2, 3])
expect([1, 2, 3]).not_to eq([2, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

not documented very well but i added links anyways:

### Rspec3 [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/built-in-matchers)

`expect(actual).to eq(expected)`

---

### Rspec2 [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers)

`expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array([2, 3, 1])`

Comment: Both expect(actual).to eq(expected) and expect(actual).to match_array(expected) work in rspec3, but they are doing different things. #match_array ignores the ordering, while #eq does not.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the OP specifically asked to disregard the order.

Comment: Yes! This worked for me.  A comparison that fails if the order of elements is not the same.  Thank you!   I refer to the `.to eq` method, not the `match_array` .