# Check if two arrays have the same contents (in any order)

Tags: ruby, arrays, comparison

I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 with Rails 1.2.3, and need to determine whether two arrays have the same elements, regardless of whether or not they're in the same order. One of the arrays is guaranteed not to contain duplicates (the other might, in which case the answer is no).

My first thought was

```
require 'set'
a.to_set == b.to_set
```

but I was wondering if there was a more efficient or idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby - Does array A contain all elements of array B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890717/ruby-does-array-a-contain-all-elements-of-array-b)

Comment: Try array.should =~ another_array
 
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978922/rspec-array-should-another-array-but-without-concern-for-order

Comment: You could have saved a lot of confusion by: 1) stating whether the elements of the arrays are necessarily sortable; and 2) provide a simple example to clarify what you mean by, "whether two arrays have the same elements" (e.g., do `[1,2]` and `[2,1,1]` have the same elements?)

Comment: Ruby 2.6 has introduced `difference` which offers a solution both very fast and very readable. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919783/check-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-contents-in-any-order/56739603#answer-56739603)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

This doesn't require conversion to set:

```
a.sort == b.sort
```

Comment: No conversion? What is `.uniq.sort` then? Besides `uniq` is similar to `to_set` internally plus additional `.to_a.sort`

Comment: Accepting this since it's closest to what I ended up using, though without the `uniq`s. Actually I ended up creating one of the arrays with `Range#to_a`, so I only had to `sort` the other one.

Comment: This won't work if the array contains elements that cannot be simply sorted (e.g. an array of hashes). sahil dhankhar's solution appears to be a more general solution.

Comment: Painfully simple, for small Arrays where performance of sorting them isn't too costly. Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

for two arrays A and B:
A and B have same contents if:
`(A-B).blank? and (B-A).blank?`

or you can just check for:
`((A-B) + (B-A)).blank?`

Also as suggested by @cort3z this solution als0 works for polymorphic arrays i.e

```
 A = [1 , "string", [1,2,3]]
 B = [[1,2,3] , "string", 1]
 (A-B).blank? and (B-A).blank? => true
 # while A.uniq.sort == B.uniq.sort will throw error `ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed`
```

::::::::::: EDIT :::::::::::::

As suggested in the comments, above solution fails for duplicates.Although as per the question that is not even required since the asker is not interested in duplicates(he is converting his arrays to set before checking and that masks duplicates and even if you look at the accepeted answer he is using a .uniq operator before checking and that too masks duplicates.). But still if duplicates interests you ,Just adding a check of count will fix the same(as per the question only one array can contain duplicates). So the final solution will be:
`A.size == B.size and ((A-B) + (B-A)).blank?`

Comment: This will fail if either array contains duplicates. E.g., if `A=[1]` and `B=[1,1]`, both `(A-B)` and `(B-A)` will return blank. See [Array Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

Comment: @dafrazzman totally agree with you. I have modified my answer to incorporate your feedback.But if you have a close look at the question(or the accepted answer), asker is using:
`a.to_set == b.to_set`  and the accepted answer is using `a.uniq.sort == b.uniq.sort` and both give exact same result as `((A-B) + (B-A)).blank?` for A=[1] and B=[1,1] agree ? Since he was just asking for an improvement over his original solution , my original solution still works :) . agree?

Comment: This solution is quite nice since it handles objects of multiple types. Say you have `A = [123, "test", [], some_object, nil]` and `B = A#because I am lazy`, then `A.uniq.sort` will throw error (comparison of string and Array failed).

Comment: Would this be O(n) then since it's dependent on the array size? (linear)

Comment: It wouldn't work if the arrays have same size but the repeated elements are not the same. For instance `A = [1, 1, 2]` and `B = [1, 2, 2]`

Comment: #blank? is Rails specific.  Not everybody is in Rails-land...  Use std library method #empty?

Answer (score 40):

**Ruby 2.6+**

Ruby's introduced [`difference`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-difference) in 2.6.

This gives a very fast, very readable solution here, as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a.difference(b).any?
# => false
a.difference(b.reverse).any?
# => false

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3]
a.difference(b).any?
# => true
```

However, the reverse isn't true:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.difference(b).any?
# => false
```

This means to get the difference in both directions it is necessary to run:

```
a.difference(b).any? || b.difference(a).any?
```

Running the benchmarks:

```
a = Array.new(1000) { rand(100) }
b = Array.new(1000) { rand(100) }

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('sort')   { a.sort == b.sort }  
  x.report('sort!')  { a.sort! == b.sort! }  
  x.report('to_set') { a.to_set == b.to_set }  
  x.report('minus')  { ((a - b) + (b - a)).empty? }  
  x.report('difference') { a.difference(b).any? }
  x.report('difference two way') { a.difference(b).any? || b.difference(a).any? }
end

                sort     10.175k (± 6.2%) i/s -     50.778k in   5.015112s
               sort!     10.513k (± 6.8%) i/s -     53.212k in   5.089106s
              to_set      4.953k (± 8.8%) i/s -     24.570k in   5.037770s
               minus     15.290k (± 6.6%) i/s -     77.520k in   5.096902s
          difference     25.481k (± 7.9%) i/s -    126.600k in   5.004916s
  difference two way     12.652k (± 8.3%) i/s -     63.232k in   5.038155s
```

My takeaway would be that `difference` is a great choice for a one directional diff.

If you need to check in both directions, it's a balance between performance and readability. For me, the readability pips it, but that's a call to be made on a case by case basis.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 26):

Speed comparsions

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'set'

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('sort')   { a.sort == b.sort }  
  x.report('sort!')  { a.sort! == b.sort! }  
  x.report('to_set') { a.to_set == b.to_set }  
  x.report('minus')  { ((a - b) + (b - a)).empty? }  
end  

Warming up --------------------------------------
            sort    88.338k i/100ms
           sort!   118.207k i/100ms
          to_set    19.339k i/100ms
           minus    67.971k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
            sort      1.062M (± 0.9%) i/s -      5.389M in   5.075109s
           sort!      1.542M (± 1.2%) i/s -      7.802M in   5.061364s
          to_set    200.302k (± 2.1%) i/s -      1.006M in   5.022793s
           minus    783.106k (± 1.5%) i/s -      3.942M in   5.035311s
```

Comment: btw order of elemetns does not affect `sort`'s speed

Comment: Surprised me... I expected _by-set_ comparison to outperform all others due to sets lookup O(n) time complexity. So that any well implemented sort would require O(n logn). Whereas casting to sets and looking up values would overall make it in O(n) time.

Comment: I'd expect `to_set` to start outperforming with large enough arrays where O(n logn) would start mattering more than the effort required to convert array to set

Comment: This is helpful, but not really an answer in itself? Perhaps better adding this to an existing solution?

Comment: In `minus`, it's a pity to build the union.  `(a - b).empty? && (b - a).empty?`.

Answer (score 18):

When the elements of `a` and `b` are [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Comparable.html),

```
a.sort == b.sort
```

Correction of @mori's answer based on @steenslag's comment

Comment: ...when `a` and `b` can be sorted.

Answer (score 8):

If you expect `[:a, :b] != [:a, :a, :b]` `to_set` doesn't work. You can use frequency instead:

```
class Array
  def frequency
    p = Hash.new(0)
    each{ |v| p[v] += 1 }
    p
  end
end

[:a, :b].frequency == [:a, :a, :b].frequency #=> false
[:a, :b].frequency == [:b, :a].frequency #=> true
```

Comment: why not just `a.sort == b.sort` if he cares about frequency?

Comment: @fl00r What if items are not comparable? `["", :b].frequency == [:b, ""].frequency #=> true`

Comment: also you can do something functional as `a.group_by{|i| i} == b.group_by{|i| i}`

Answer (score 7):

If you know the arrays are of equal length and neither array contains duplicates then this works too:

```
( array1 & array2 ) == array1
```

**Explanation:** the `&` operator in this case returns a copy of a1 sans any items not found in a2, which is the same as the original a1 iff both arrays have the same contents with no duplicates.

**Analyis:** Given that the order is unchanged, I'm guessing this is implemented as a double iteration so consistently `O(n*n)`, notably worse for large arrays than `a1.sort == a2.sort` which should perform with worst-case `O(n*logn)`.

Comment: Doesn't work always: `a1 = [1,2,3], a2 = [2, 1, 3]`   `a1 && a2` returns `[2,1,3]` for me which is not equal to `a1`

Comment: @Kaylan, don't you mean it only works when `a1==a2`? It may work if `array1` on the right side of the equality is replaced by `array2`, but I doubt that the order of the elements returned by `&` is guaranteed.

Comment: @KalyanRaghu `&` is a set intersection operator for arrays, `&&` is logical AND - they are very different!

Answer (score 5):

combining `&` and `size` may be fast too.

```rb
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'set'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('sort')   { a.sort == b.sort }  
  x.report('sort!')  { a.sort! == b.sort! }  
  x.report('to_set') { a.to_set == b.to_set }  
  x.report('minus')  { ((a - b) + (b - a)).empty? }
  x.report('&.size') { a.size == b.size && (a & b).size == a.size }  
end  

Calculating -------------------------------------
                sort    896.094k (±11.4%) i/s -      4.458M in   5.056163s
               sort!      1.237M (± 4.5%) i/s -      6.261M in   5.071796s
              to_set    224.564k (± 6.3%) i/s -      1.132M in   5.064753s
               minus      2.230M (± 7.0%) i/s -     11.171M in   5.038655s
              &.size      2.829M (± 5.4%) i/s -     14.125M in   5.010414s
```

Comment: `&`  description from ruby official doc `Set Intersection — Returns a new array containing unique elements common to the two arrays. The order is preserved from the original array.`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to iterate over the array with no duplicates

```
# assume array a has no duplicates and you want to compare to b
!a.map { |n| b.include?(n) }.include?(false)
```

This returns an array of trues.  If any false appears, then the outer `include?` will return true.  Thus you have to invert the whole thing to determine if it's a match.

Comment: @Victor Moroz, you're correct, and a frequency count would simply be O(n).

Comment: This won't work when `b` includes all the elements of `a` plus some extra