# Rspec - Check if an array have same elements than other, regardless of the order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm not sure if its a Rspec question, but I only encountred this problem on Rspec tests.

I want to check if an array is equal to another array, regardless of the elements order :

```
[:b, :a, :c] =?= [:a, :b, :c]
```

My current version :

```
my_array.length.should == 3
my_array.should include(:a)
my_array.should include(:b)
my_array.should include(:c)
```

Is there any method on Rspec, ruby or Rails for do something like this :

```
my_array.should have_same_elements_than([:a, :b, :c])
```

Regards

Comment: Similar to [Rspec: “array.should == another_array” but without concern for order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2978922/567863)

Comment: Use the newer Rspec `contain_exactly` -- see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ***was*** my ***wrong*** matcher (thanks @steenslag):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_same_array_as do |expected_array|
  match do |actual_array|
    (actual_array | expected_array) - (actual_array & expected_array) == []
  end
end
```

Other solutions:

- use the builtin matcher, best solution
- use `Set`:

Something like:

```
require 'set'
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_same_array_as do |expected_array|
  match do |actual_array|
    Set.new(actual_array) == Set.new(expected_array)
  end
end
```

Comment: What an elegant solution ! Thanks ! I knew `&`, but you learned me the operator `|`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this fails when there are duplicates: [3,2,1,1] and [1,2,3] returns true.

Comment: @steenslag: `([3,2,1,1] | [1,2,3] - [3,2,1,1] & [1,2,3])
=> [3, 2, 1]` and `([1,2 ,3] | [3, 2, 1, 1] - [1, 2, 3] & [3, 2, 1, 1])=> [1, 2, 3]` this doesn't return true since it's different from `[]`

Comment: `spec/support/custom_matchers.rb` is where I store this

Comment: @apneadiving In your post you are doing `([3,2,1,1] | [1,2,3]) - ([3,2,1,1] & [1,2,3])` which is different from your comment (result: [])

Comment: @apneadiving [3,2,1,1] and [1,2,3,2] still failing. I guess this is why Array does not have a `^` method like Set .

Comment: @steenslag: you've made my day :)

Comment: There is no need to go through all this.  Just use the builtin operator `=~` like in Stefan's answer.

Comment: The answer includes two custom matchers, which is extremely bad practice when a builtin operator is available.

Comment: @messick: yes I didn't delete my first anser ubt I wrote `use the builtin matcher, best solution` what else do you need?

Comment: Downvote because: The answer is very NOT straightforward. Users tend to read quickly, and won't see your _best solution_ part. Plus It is unclear.

Answer (score 37):

There is a `match_array` matcher in RSpec which does this:

http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:match_array

Comment: damn, didn't know that, +1

Comment: Best solution for many people, but I can't install RSpec > 2.11.

Comment: `contain_exactly` does the trick as well, for a splatted array (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48206163/6320039)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `=~` operator:

```
[:b, :a, :c].should =~ [:a, :b, :c] # pass
```

From the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:match_array):

> Passes if actual contains all of the expected regardless of order.
>   This works for collections. Pass in multiple args and it will only
>   pass if all args are found in collection.

For RSpec's *expect* syntax there's `match_array`:

```
expect([:b, :a, :c]).to match_array([:a, :b, :c]) # pass
```

or `contain_exactly` if you're passing single elements:

```
expect([:b, :a, :c]).to contain_exactly(:a, :b, :c) # pass
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
[:b, :a, :c].sort == [:a, :b, :c].sort
```

Comment: Missing a `should`. In any case, @Stefan has the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think all answers seems to be pretty old.
Latest matcher is `contain_exactly`.

You can simply do -

```
expect([:b, :a, :c]).to contain_exactly(:a, :b, :c)
```

Please not that in `contain_exactly` we don't pass a whole array, instead pass `separate` elements.

Ref - [Rspec Guide](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-6/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher)